# NGINX X-Accel-Redirect doesn't pass Content-Type automatically?

Tags: nginx, content-type, x-sendfile, x-accel-redirect

Doesn't (or can't) NGINX's X-Accel-Redirect automatically pass the Content-Type header based on the file?

The NGINX part:

```
location /file {
    rewrite /file/(.+) /file.php?params=$1 last;
}

location ~ /files {
    internal;
    root /path/to/files;
}
```

PHP:

```
$filename = '/files/test.png';
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename = ' . $filename);
header('X-Accel-Redirect: ' . $filename);
```

I have to add `header('Content-type: image/png');` to display the png directly, otherwise the server will return `text/html`

Isn't there a way to get the content type directly from NGINX?
Or is this a bad idea (perhaps performance)? I could store the content type in the database with all the other stuff, that's not problem. Just wonder why it doesn't work.

Looks like this helps...

```
header('Content-type:');
```

but why?

Thanks!